# How can i call the opencart api to get all products and orders?

Tags: api, opencart

I was having a hard time figuring out on getting the product list and order list through postman. I tried to refer on this site [site](https://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=marketplace/extension/info&extension_id=23394&filter_search=API) and also all the apis on this site [site](http://docs.opencart.com/en-gb/system/users/api/) but its not working, it always shows "The page you requested cannot be found!" (please see attached file).[screenshot error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/srQyy.png)

Hoping for your help.

Thank you,

Ryan Jayme

Answer (score 0):

Yea, you can't without a plugin from marketplace. And that documentation is outdated and that API is meant to be used by website admin not by other services/scripts